# XPATH: creating a list of unique with data from non-unique, using arrays or disting

Tags: arrays, xml, xslt, xpath, distinct

I have an xml like this:

```
<Income>
    <Currency>USD</Currency>
    <Description>Bank Payment</Description>
    <Sum>300.82</Sum>
</Income>
<Income>
    <Currency>EUR</Currency>
    <Description>Bank Payment</Description>
    <Sum>100</Sum>
</Income>
<Income>
    <Currency>USD</Currency>
    <Description>Cash</Description>
    <Sum>500</Sum>
</Income>
```

I need this data to be sorted by the currency. There could be several blocks with the same currency, in this case I need to take from there sums and put them to existing currency. Here is what I would like to get:

```
<Payment>
    <Currency>USD</Currency>
    <BankPayment>300.82</BankPayment>
    <Cash>500</Cash>
</Payment>
<Payment>
    <Currency>EUR</Currency>
    <BankPayment>100</BankPayment>
</Payment>
```

I suppose that I can use arrays here or distinct, but I don't know how to handle with data from non-unique items. 
Is there a way to solve this problem? (I can use only Xpath 1.0)
Thanks for help!

Comment: It is a grouping problem which can be solved in XSLT 1.0 using Muenchian grouping http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml.

Comment: It's not a good idea to name tags this way

Comment: @RudolfYurgenson : I'm new to XML, do you mean that there should be a "group" tag as well, ie. `<Incomes><Income>...</Income></Incomes>` (and same for `<Payments>....`? ). Thanks for any comment.

Comment: I mean that it's a bad practice to generate tags with names based on text content of other nodes. I'd prefer <Sum type="Bank Payment"> instead of <Bank Payment>

Comment: @RudolfYurgenson :  I haven't seen that distinction made before. Thanks for the pointer! Good luck to all.

Comment: @RudolfYurgenson: OP's tag naming is fine and is consistent with common conventions and proper semantic naming.   It's generally better to convey the nature of an element via its name rather than via a `@type` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <xsl:key name="ccy" match="Income" use="Currency" />
  <xsl:template match="start">
    <xsl:for-each select="Income[count(. | key('ccy', Currency)[1]) = 1]">
      <xsl:sort select="Currency" />
      <xsl:element name="Payment">
        <xsl:element name="CurCode">
      <xsl:value-of select="Currency" />
        </xsl:element>
      <xsl:for-each select="key('ccy', Currency)">
        <xsl:sort select="Description" />
        <xsl:element name="{Description}">
          <xsl:value-of select="Sum" />
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

**NOTE** that `<Description>` values should not contain any spaces, otherwise you could get incorrect xml element name (xml doesn't support tag names with spaces).

Comment: That's why it's bad to use arbitrary data as tag names

Comment: Note that XSLT allows you to create result elements literally so instead of `<xsl:element name="Payment>...</xsl:element>` you can simply write `<Payment>...</Payment>`. Only in the case of `<xsl:element name="{Description}">` where you want to compute an element name based on input data you need `xsl:element`.